# Code Keeps saying: "[Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' for argument '1' to 'void test(float, int)'"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void test(float, int);

int main()
{ 
    const int size=11;
    float a[size];

    test(a, size);

    return 0;
}

void test(float a[], int size)
{
    [....]
}
```

it points to test(a, size); but I can't figure out whats wrong(I'm also learning coding and just learned about arrays/confused)

Comment: why do you pre-declare test with float and then implement it with float[]?

Comment: Your parameter `float a[]` really means `float *a`. Do you want `a` to be a `float` or a pointer to a `float`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function prototype `void test(float, int);` does not match your function `void test(float a[], int size)`. Change the prototype at the top to `void test(float a[], int size);` (I like to leave the input variable names in the prototype for consistency, but this is not necessary).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: FYI, you should probably remove the "Why isn't my code working?" part from the title of your question to prevent it from getting downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to write:

```
void test(float*, int);
// ...
void test(float* a, int size)
{
    [....]
}
```

when test is called with array argument, array will decay to pointer to its first element - and its size will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong parameter type for the test forward deceleration.

Try this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void test(float *, int);

int main()
{ 
    const int size=11;
    float a[size];

    test(a, size);

    return 0;
}

void test(float a[], int size)
{

}
```